# Spring cache not working for overriden methods in a subclass

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

I can't get Spring cache to work correctly with methods overriden in a subclass also implemented in the superclass.
For example, I have this abstract service:

```
public interface CrudService<E, I> {
  void deleteById(I id);
  E create(E item);
}
public abstract class CrudServiceImpl<E, I> {
  void deleteById(I id) { // do things }
  ...
}
```

I have several services extending this abstract class for different entities (E) and id types (I). I only want to cache one of them:

```
public interface LocationService extends CrudService<Location, String> {
   @CacheEvict("location")
   @Override
   void deleteById(String id);

   @Cacheable("location")
   List<Location> find();
}

@Service
public class LocationServiceImpl extends CrudServiceImpl<Location, String> implements LocationService {
   public List<Location> find() { // do things }
}
```

Method *find* is only defined in LocationService, not in the abstract class.
When I call those methods from a component that also has an abstract class:

```
public abstract class CrudManager<E, I> {
    @Autowired
    private CrudService<E, I> crudService; 

   public void doDelete(I id) {
      crudService.deleteById(id);
   }
}

@Component
public class LocationManager extends CrudManager<Location, String> {
   @Autowired
   private LocationService locationService;

   public List<Location> doFind() {
      return locationService.find();
   }
}
```

I have confirmed that when `LocationManager.doFind` is called, it triggers cache operations defined in LocationService, but `LocationManager.doDelete` don't.

I have debugged until AbstractFallbackCacheOperationSource.getCacheOperations to realize that the method it's searching operations for is:

```
public default void com.ontech.plantcore.service.LocationService.deleteById(java.lang.Object)
```

with targetClass = LocationServiceImpl.class, instead of my annotated method that is LocationService.deleteById(java.lang.String). So ClassUtils.getMostSpecificMethod fails to find the annotated method and no operations are returned. It happens with Spring 4.3.14 and 4.1.9.

If I add an specific call in LocationManager to locationService.deleteById it works, but that's just ruining the inheritance.

I see it's dued to type erasure, but I don't know how to make it works correctly?

Comment: Where is the code about `LocationManager.create`?

Comment: I didn't include it for simplification. Sorry, I've just changed the example method and completed some missing parameters.

Comment: Sharing a link to a github repo would be much more convenient rather than parse code in text. What version of Spring Framework is this?

Comment: Spring 4.3.14 and 4.1.9 too. Well, the example is rather simple.

Comment: Same issue for Spring 5.3.14 - any luck finding a solution?

Answer (score 1):

In [Spring Cache Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) says `@Cache*` annotation on interface method does not work with class-based proxies. So you should add `@Cache*` to each class method that want to cache.

> Spring recommends that you only annotate concrete classes (and methods
>   of concrete classes) with the @Cache* annotation, as opposed to
>   annotating interfaces. You certainly can place the @Cache* annotation
>   on an interface (or an interface method), but this works only as you
>   would expect it to if you are using interface-based proxies. The fact
>   that Java annotations are not inherited from interfaces means that if
>   you are using class-based proxies (proxy-target-class="true") or the
>   weaving-based aspect (mode="aspectj"), then the caching settings are
>   not recognized by the proxying and weaving infrastructure, and the
>   object will not be wrapped in a caching proxy, which would be
>   decidedly bad.

Comment: I didn't say anytime I'm using class-based proxies. I'm not using them indeed which is the default configuration, so it's correct to annotate interfaces. Anyway, I already tried putting the annotations in the classes and does change nothing. I checked the object is wrapped with a proxy. But the problem is with the Spring Code that detects if a method has cache annotations, that due to type erasure the method is missed.